# Two quick parametrization questions

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm reading these notes:

https://web.stanford.edu/class/math220a/handouts/firstorder.pdf

and on page 06 I'm stuck on this part:

> > Consider the curve $\Gamma = { (x, t): x − at = 0 }$ in the $xt$-plane, parametrized by $r$ such that $\Gamma = { (r, ar) }$. Now we prescribe a boundary condition on $\Gamma$ such that we ask that $u|_\Gamma = \phi$. We claim this problem is ill-posed. Why?

My first question is then: shouldn't the parametrization be $(r,\frac{r}{a})$, or, equivalently, $(ar,r)$? As in, I take $x = r$, then $at = r \implies t = \frac{r}{a}$?

I'm also stuck on this part, still on page 06:

> > In order to guarantee that we can do so, we ask that the curve $\Gamma$ be nowhere tangent to the vector field $(a,1)$. If $\Gamma$ satisfies this condition, we say $\Gamma$ is noncharacteristic.

Isn't the tangent to $(r,ar)$ just $(1,a)$ everywhere? How is this curve then "tangent to the vector field $(a,1)$"?

I know these must be dumb questions, so I appreciate any help.